# getComputedStyle of a clone element which is not in the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clone

I have a html page like;

```
<div id="cloneDiv">
    <h1>
        <a href="">ASUS Vivotab Smart Black Office 2013 H&S ME400C-C2-BK 10.1-Inch 64GB Tablet
            (Black)</a>
    </h1>
    <div id="fordBackgroundImage" style="display: inline-block; background-position: center center; width: 1200px;
        height: 565px; background-image: url('http://www.ford.com/ngbs-services/resources/ford/edge/2013/npcolorizer/edg13_ingotsilver.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; position: relative;">
        <div style="position: absolute; color: white; font-weight: bold; top: 50px; left: 100px; font-size: 50px;">
            Try new ford jeep!
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <img alt="" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81UsKLK%2B6LL._SX342_.jpg"
            class="border thumb0 selected" style="cursor: pointer;">
    </p>
    <p>
        <img border="0" src="http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/kindle/otter/dp/o1_slate_sm._V358729399_.jpg"
            style="width: 320px; height: 282px;">
    </p>
 </div>
```

and I have a javascript function to convert element to computed style element;

```
function MakeCssInline(elementParam) {
var domE = $(elementParam).get()[0];
var cssText = window.getComputedStyle(domE).cssText;
$(elementParam).attr("style", cssText);
// children
var items = domE.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var domE2 = items[i];
    var cssText2 = window.getComputedStyle(domE2).cssText;
    $(items[i]).attr("style", cssText2);
}
 };
```

If I call function on original element it works; but it changes original element html

```
MakeCssInline($("#cloneDiv"));
```

But When I try to call this function on cloned element it does not work;

```
var cloneElement = $("#cloneDiv").clone();
MakeCssInline(cloneElement);
```

it does not apply styles to element because I did not append in the body element,
since I do not want to mess with original element, is there any way to get computed style clone of an element with javascript?

Comment: Since the element wasn't added to the DOM, no style was computed for it yet. However, you might be able to get the computed style of the original element and assign it to the cloned element.

Comment: if you copy the style attrib, it should cascade the same when added to the dom, no need to specify such specific values...

Comment: @FelixKling this is a nice trick, tried and working now, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a very basic function that follows Felix Kling's suggestion;

```
function MakeCssInline(elementParam) {
    var cloned = $(elementParam).clone();
    $(cloned).find("script").remove();
    $(cloned).find("link").remove();
    $(cloned).find("iframe").remove();
    //
    var domE = $(elementParam).get()[0];
    var domCloned = $(cloned).get()[0];
    //
    var cssText = window.getComputedStyle(domE).cssText;
    $(cloned).attr("style", cssText);
    // children
    var items = domE.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var itemsCloned = domCloned.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var domE2 = items[i];
        var cssText2 = window.getComputedStyle(domE2).cssText;
        $(itemsCloned[i]).attr("style", cssText2);
    }
    return domCloned;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to append the elemnt to the body, hidden, rip the info you need, then remove it from DOM.

Comment: Computed style for a duplicate element will differ from one for the original element. Even if you appended it to the original `parentNode` rather than `body`, CSS selectors often determine style based on a position relative to other nodes. But even if you temporarily removed the original element and replaced it with the duplicate *in situ,* there is still an issue of CSS properties altered dynamically by some page scripts in response to some events that won’t be reproduced.